# setSize() doesn't work to set browser size in selenium using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to resize browser window after launching with below javascript

```
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().window().setSize(1200,800);
```

However, I'm getting an error

> 'setSize is not a function\n'.

Could someone please help me in resolving the issue, I have tried `reSizeTo()` as well

Comment: I just found a solution for my question, below code works

driver.manage().window().setRect({width: 640, height: 480, x, y});

Comment: then post is as an answer instead of putting it in the comment

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added it as answer. Thank you @EugenSunic

Answer (score 7):

I just found a solution for my question, below code works

```
driver.manage().window().setRect({width: 640, height: 480, x, y});
```

Answer (score 2):

This function in 2022 :

```js
var width = 800;
var height = 600;

driver.manage().window().setRect({x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height});
```

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

Answer (score 1):

From selenium doc: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Window.html

it doesn't have method `setSize`, you should use `setRect` instead